# Knuth the art of computer programming ex 1.1.8

Tags: algorithm, greatest-common-divisor, knuth, taocp

I can't figure out what Knuth meant in his instructions for an exercise 8 from Chapter 1.1.

The task is to make an efficient gcd algorithm of two positive integers `m` and `n` using his notation `theta[j]`, `phi[j]`, `b[j]` and `a[j]` where theta and phi are strings and `a` and `b` -  positive integers which represent computational steps in this case.

Let an input be the string of the form `a^mb^n`.

An excellent explanation of Knuth's algorithm is given by [schnaader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34065/schnaader) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575215/the-art-of-computer-programming-exercise-question-chapter-1-question-8/575315?s=15%7C2.9207#575315).

**My question is** how this may be connected with the direction given in the exercise to use his Algorithm E given in the book with original `r` (remainder) substituted by `|m-n|` and `n` substituted by `min(m,n)`.

Comment: This question may be better suited for the [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I think it's ok here and also on cs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Knuth says "Let the input be represented by the string `a^mb^n`", what he means is that the input should take the form of `m` number of `a`s and `n` number of `b`s. So the input `f((m,n))` where `m = 3` and `n = 2` would be represented by the string `aaabb`.

Take a moment to look back at his equation 3 in that chapter, which represents a [Markov algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_algorithm). (below)

```
        f((σ,j)) = (σ,a_j)        if θ_j does not occur in σ
        f((σ,j)) = (αφ_jω,b_j)    if α is the shortest string for which σ = αθ_jω
        f((σ,N)) = (σ,N)
```

So the idea is to define the sequence for each variable `j, θ_j, φ_j, a_j & b_j`. This way, using the above Markov's algorithm you can specify what happens to your input string, depending on the value of `j`.

Now, to get onto your main question;

> My question is how this may be connected with the direction given in the excercise to use his Algorithm E given in the book with original r (remainder) substituted by |m-n| and n substituted by min(m,n).

Essentially what Knuth is saying here, is that you can't do division with the above Markov's algorithm. So what's the closest thing to division?  Well, essentially we can subtract the smaller number from the larger number until we're left with a remainder. For example;

`10 % 4 = 2` is the same as doing the following;

```
        10 - 4 = 6        Can we remove another 4? Yes. Do it again.
        6  - 4 = 2        Can we remove another 4? No. We have our remainder.
```

And now we have our remainder. This is essentially what he wants you to do with our input string eg `aaabb`.

If you read through Knuth's suggested answer in the back of the book and work through a couple of examples you will see that this is essentially what he is doing by removing the pairs `ab` and then adding a `c` until no more pairs `ab` exist. Taking the example I used at the top we get the string being manipulated as such `aaabb, aab, caab, ca, cca, ccb, aab (then start again)`

Which is the same as `r = m % n, m = n, n = r (then start again)`. The difference is of course that in the above we have used the modulus operator and division, but in the example above that we have only used subtraction.

I hope this helps. I actually [wrote a more in-depth analysis of Knuth's variation on a Markov algorithm](http://www.rudikershaw.com/articles/computationalmethod3) on my blog. So if you're still feeling a little stuck have a read through the series.

Answer (score 0):

So, I attempted a solution but I would like some correction if possible.
Based on Rudi's answer ,in-depth analyisis of the Markov algorithm, and the hints provided in the book, I achieved these set of transition rules below for the string, although they are not simple transitions. The books asks you te be "as simple as possible" and I guess checking `m>n` and `m-n >0` is not as simple as only making string substitutions as the Markov Algorithm specifies. But still, it's an attempt:

```
1. a^m b^n -> a^(m-n) b^n, if m-n > 0;
2. a^0 b^n -> a^0 b^n, the algorithm ends and n is the answer;
3. a^m b^n -> a^n b^m, if n > m
```

it working against a^13 b^3:

```
f(a^13 b^3, 0) = (a^10 b^3, 1)
f(a^10 b^3, 1) = (a^7 b^3, 1)
... keep applying rule 1 until:
f(a^1 b^3, 1) = (a^3 b^1, 3)
f(a^3 b^1, 3) = (a^2 b^1, 1)
... keep applying rule 1 until:
f(a^0 b^1, 1) = (a^0 b^1, 2), 1 is the answer.  ∎
```

Also, my rules specifiy the hints |m-n| and n <- min(m,n), showing the connection between the direction given, as you asked in the original question.